# SCRIPT5 : Access is denied on IE-10 after Security Update : jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jsp

There was an IE-10 security update on Sept-10. After that, in my application there seems to be an issue accessing a standard div using jquery.

Here is the quick scenario :

I have a jsp layout template where there is a div defined :

```
<div id="abc"></div>
```

In that I include a js file k1.js, the following function in that is triggered upon a click of a button

```
function sample() {
jQuery.get("/fetchmedata.do?a=true", function(data) {
    jQuery("#abc").html(data);
});
```

This was totally functioning across all browsers including ie-10 till Sept -10. After 10th, it still works fine on IE-9 and old IE-10 builds, but on new IE-10 build throws the error in console :

```
SCRIPT5 : Access is denied
```

The call stack pointed to internals of Jquery code which I couldn't decipher/understand the context.

The quick fix was to replace the jquery with Javascript, and it worked :

```
function sample() {
 jQuery.get("/fetchmedata.do?a=true", function(data) {
    document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = data;
 });
```

The jquery version was jquery-1.4.4.min.js.

Please advice on what could have been the issue, is it again probably related to not using XDomainRequest instead of XHR, so that we could take precautions in the code to avoid future issues.

Also what is the best practices around it ?

Please advice.

Comment: it's a same-domain request, therefore xdr vs xhr shouldn't matter. My guess is the issue is somehow related to the structure of the html/text being returned. In more recent versions of jQuery you'd get around it by using $.parseHTML, but that isn't available in that old version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when u say structure of html/text being returned, could please elaborate as this was totally working prior to the security update, and even after that on all other versions of IE..

Comment: the structure such as.... `<div>somecontent</div>` in this case the structure is just a div with some text. if the html returned contains anything that could possibly be interpreted differently in one browser version vs another, you could have issues.

Comment: This particular error you are getting though is interesting. It's likely not related to the structure at all, but more so related to where the code is located in the page and when it is executing.

Comment: Thanks kevin for the reply. How do we typically debug these scenarios.. IE-10 F12 developer tools takes me right to the jquery internals where the exception occurs, tracing that back brings me to the line of code I shared. So coming out of this discussion there seems to be only one way out to proactively avoid future issues, i.t to upgrade out Jquery version.

Comment: does upgrading jQuery fix it? that would suggest it's a bug in jQuery that was fixed in a later version. If that's the case, we could research that bug to see what they changed to fix it to see if we can monkeypatch 1.4.4 to make it work (that or you can just stay upgraded of course)